# How to find index of minimum element in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series:

```
0     0.0149
1    0.00088
2    0.00322
3    0.00357
4     0.0101
```

Of type and shape: dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> (5,)

I am trying to return the index of the minimum element +1, in this case 2

I have tried the following methods idxmin() and argmin() but keep getting

> TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values of `Series` to numeric before using [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
out = s.astype(float).idxmin() + 1
```